# extract family name, mother surname and names from table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Hi i need to extract family name, mother surname and names and name of a table its mainly compose of Latin names so most people have 2 names +, i find a way to make work with the code below.
my question is if there is a better way to do it?

```
Declare @t table ( [Name] varchar(100) ) 
    insert into @t ( Name )
    VALUES ('Gomez Flores Roberto'), ('DELGADO PEREZ MARIA TERESA'), ('MARTINEZ VELASCO MARTIN AGUSTIN DOMINGO'), ('BURGOS JIMENEZ ERNESTO')
    SELECT
     substring(name,0,charindex(' ',name)) as LasName
    ,substring(substring(name, charindex(' ',name)+1,(len(name)- charindex(' ',name))),0,charindex(' ',substring(name, charindex(' ',name)+1,(len(name)- charindex(' ',name))))) MiddleName
    ,substring(substring(name, charindex(' ',name)+1,(len(name)- charindex(' ',name))), charindex(' ',substring(name, charindex(' ',name)+1,(len(name)- charindex(' ',name))))+1,(len(substring(name, charindex(' ',name)+1,(len(name)- charindex(' ',name))))- charindex(' ',substring(name, charindex(' ',name)+1,(len(name)- charindex(' ',name)))))) as Name
    FROM @t
```

Thank you for you time  and help

Comment: The best approach is to store the values in separate columns - firstname, lastname etc

Comment: There isn't a better way to do it, because you're going to have all kinds of exceptions that violate your existing rules. `Dennis de la Mosely-Williams` and `Oscar van der Nutz III`, that kind of thing. Data cleansing tools are expensive for exactly this reason.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks ill be working on those after im done with this.

Comment: @TGH that's what im doing. But data is already stored that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be beneficial to count how many names each value in @t.name has. for example Gomez Flores Roberto has 3 and DELGADO PEREZ MARIA TERESA has 4. Getting the max count from them would tell you how may fields you will need and would allow you to do some data cleansing or truncating after a certain amount. 
found this great article that might help.

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3233/name-parsing-with-sql-server-functions-and-tsql-programming/